# What is meant by pointwise fixed?

Tags: general-topology

I did not find a direct definition so I will give the context :

> $X$ is compact manifold with boundary. There is no smooth map $f:X\rightarrow \partial X$ that leaves $\partial X$ pointwise fixed.

Here what is meant by pointwise fixed?
I found that fixed means $f(x)=x$ so pointwise means this must be true for all $x$? I am not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that every individual $x \in \partial X$ is fixed by $f$, i.e. $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \partial X$.

In contrast, fixing $\partial X$ "setwise" would mean that $f(x) \in \partial X$ for all $x \in \partial X$.